# Add a specific character to a colum value if not nan python pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I would like to add a specific character to a colum value if is not a nan value.

My df :

```
var 1     var2
prod A    100
prod b    NaN
```

My result expected :

```
var1      var2
prodA     100T
prodb     NaN
```

I tried that :

```
df['var2'] = df['var2'].astype(str) + "T"
```

But the result is not good :

```
var1      var2
prodA     100T
prodb     nanT
```

Someone could help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['var2'].mask(df['var2'].notna(),df['var2'].astype(str)+'T',inplace=True)
print(df)

    var  1    var2
0  prod  A  100.0T
1  prod  b     NaN
```

or [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['var2'].notna(),'var2']=df.loc[df['var2'].notna(),'var2'].astype(str)+'T'
print(df)

    var  1    var2
0  prod  A  100.0T
1  prod  b     NaN
```

Comment: Small point, these are series methods (i.e. `pd.Series.mask`), not dataframe methods.

Answer (score 0):

Remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and processing with convert to strings, missing values are created after assigned back to column `var2`:

```
df['var2'] = df['var2'].dropna().astype(str) + "T"
print (df)
    var  1    var2
0  prod  A  100.0T
1  prod  b     NaN
```

Or convert first to integers and then to strings for avoid `.0` values:

```
df['var2'] = df['var2'].dropna().astype(int).astype(str) + "T"
print (df)
    var  1  var2
0  prod  A  100T
1  prod  b   NaN
```